# Error importing django-widget-tweaks on Google App Engine

Tags: python, django, google-app-engine

I am deploying a Django app on Google App Engine, but I get an error when importing django-widget-tweaks:

```
appcfg.py: error: Error parsing ./app.yaml: the library "django-widget-tweaks" is not supported
```

Is there any way to fix this, apart from not using the library?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can [install third-party libraries yourself](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27). Since this is not one of the runtime-provided third-party libraries you have to fulfill the following criteria:

> - The library must be implemented as pure Python code (no C extensions).
> - The code is uploaded to App Engine with your application code, and 
>     counts toward file quotas.
> - Use pip to install the library and the
>     vendor module to enable importing packages from the third-party
>     library directory

From what I can tell the module you want to use is fully implemented in Python, so this should be straight forward. Consult the docs on [vendoring](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/python/tools/libraries27#vendoring) for more information on how to do this.